# HTML Text & Images Not Aligning Properly

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I have created a simple HTML Google Fonts page with a logo and some text.
I have told the text to centre, it is not and is making the images go below the text.

```
    <img src="http://www.readingcricketclub.com/wp-content/themes/readingcricketclub/images/logo.png" alt="RCC" align="left" />
<p class="header">Welcome to the Reading CC Registration Form</p>
<img src="http://www.readingcricketclub.com/wp-content/themes/readingcricketclub/images/logo.png" alt="RCC" align="right" />
```

I am a real beginner, so the answer might be a "kick yourself" one.
Thanks

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7LBJ/)

Comment: So? what the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: You should just go learn basic `HTML` and `CSS`. Yes the answer is a "kick yourself one" because its basic `HTML`. Please don't just come here and ask questions like this if you haven't even started to try and learn the language.

Comment: Try to search through SO. There are a lot of similar questions with answers, which will definitely helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the second image tag above the `<p>`

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A7LBJ/1/) for it.

```
<img src="http://www.readingcricketclub.com/wp-content/themes/readingcricketclub/images/logo.png" alt="RCC" align="left" />

<img src="http://www.readingcricketclub.com/wp-content/themes/readingcricketclub/images/logo.png" alt="RCC" align="right" />
    <p class="header">Welcome to the Reading CC Registration Form</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```css
.header { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align:center; 
  font-size:30px; 
  display: inline-block;/**add this**/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the images inside the paragraph tags:

```
<p class="header"><img src="http://www.readingcricketclub.com/wp-content/themes/readingcricketclub/images/logo.png" alt="RCC" align="left" />
Welcome to the Reading CC Registration Form
<img src="http://www.readingcricketclub.com/wp-content/themes/readingcricketclub/images/logo.png" alt="RCC" align="right" /></p>
```

That will center all three elements, with the images pushed out to the sides of the page.

By default, `<p></p>` tags will make a new line on your page.  There are a lot of places on the web which will help you out with learning the basics tutorial-style.  You may find w3schools useful for plain-English descriptions of what each tag does.  For example, for the paragraph tag: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

Answer (score 0):

See this demos

[Demos](http://jsfiddle.net/A7LBJ/10/)

```
.header {  display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto; }
```

Answer (score -1):

try using
text-align:inline-block;